# Pullback of ample by generically finite is big

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible projective varieties. I would like to show that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is generically finite and $M \rightarrow Y$ is an ample line bundle, then $L = f^{\ast} M$ is big. Morally I think this is because $f$ is "finite on an open dense set" and so $L$ is "ample on an open dense set" and therefore some power gives an embedding that must have the right dimension.

But I can't quite complete the argument, first because I guess this is not precisely what generically finite means, and second since in order to say that a pullback of ample by finite is ample, I need surjectivity of $f$ or compactness of both spaces (Corollaries 1.2.13 and 1.2.28 in Lazarsfeld), both of which break when I pass to an open subset.

For reference this statement is made right under Definition 2.2.1 in Lazarsfeld.

Comment: What definition of big are you using? In your case, $L$  is nef and then to show bigness, suffices to show that $L^n>0$ (intersection product) , where $n=\dim X=\dim Y$.

Comment: Big is initially defined as having Iitaka dimension $\kappa(X,L)$ equal to the dimension of $X$. I think I see how to complete the proof as you suggest, thank you. However I am wondering based on its placement (before the result you mention) if it can be shown more "immediately."

Comment: What definition of Iitaka dimension are you using?

Comment: The maximum dimension of the closure of the image of the birational map given by the complete linear system of $L^{{\otimes}k}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since the sublinear system given by $H^0(Y,L^n)$ already gives a morphism to $Y$, the dimension is at least $=\dim Y=\dim X$, which is the maximum possible. So, the Iitaka dimension is $\dim X$.

Comment: Apologies, but can I ask you why this (sub?)linear system gives a morphism to $Y$? Thanks very much.

Comment: You have a map $Y\subset \mathbb{P}(H^0(Y,L^n))$ and you can easily check that the map from $X$ via the sublinear system just gives the map to $Y$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again!